# How many have to enter the building so their birthday matches?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

The riddle is as follows:

> Looking at his watch a doorman from an hotel in New York notices that
> 280 people are inside. Suddenly he begins to ponder the following. How
> many people should have to come later at least to be sure to find 3
> people who share the same birthday?

The alternatives given are as follows:

1. 451
2. 186
3. 220
4. 450

I found this problem in an old Logic challengers bulletin from 2000's, it doesn't have an author.
I'm confused exactly how to solve this. Is it possible to know how many should join to be sure they will have the same birthday?

I think the subtle clue is that already in the hotel there are *who knows how many people having the same birthday* or none at all.

Something tells me that it could be either joining half of the people or another set of 280 people, or the half plus one or the total plus one.

Can someone help me? Please make **answers as detailed as possible** so I can understand how to solve this. It is important to justify the answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: @Albert.Lang Gee I didn't know about that principle. So in short is it applied here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 366 distinct calendar dates in a (leap) year.

The maximum number of people that can be present with only ever two overlapping birthdays is 366 * 2 = 732. Thus, you'll need at least 733 to guarantee that there is at least one triad of shared birthdays.

733 - 280 = 453, which is none of your answers.

If, however, the problem poser simply *forgot that February 29 was a thing*, then you'd be talking about 365 * 2 = 730 as your first calculation, and 731 as the guaranteed triad number. 731 - 280 = 451.

Comment: It was very clear. But since someone mentioned above that the pigeon hole principle is related. Perhaps could you include as an addition to your answer a justification *why* would this principle applies?. I'm already accepting your answer but it would be nice if you could help me with the explanation of such principle applied here.

Comment: Pigeon hole principle: "if n items are put into m containers, with n>m, then at least one container must contain more than one item". 365 "containers" (days) -> fill each container twice, then add one more and you're guaranteed to have three in one.

Answer (score 2):

You can have up to $2\cdot 366 = 732$ people without any 3 having the same birthday.  So the required additional number of people is $732-280+1=453$.  The questioner ignored leap year, and so the intended answer must be $2\cdot 365-280+1=451$.